# How to amplify the output of a digital low pass filter?

Tags: microcontroller, filter, signal-processing, dsp, digital-filter

I have used the transfer function of a RC low pass filter to design a IIR Digital low pass filter.
\begin{equation}
H(s)=
\frac{1}{sRC+1}
;First
\space 
order 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H(s)=
\frac{1}{sRC+1}
.
\frac{1}{sRC+1}
;Second
\space 
order 
\end{equation}
As the readings of ADC are discrete signal, so I have used the Bilinear Transform to find the Z-transfom and did the inverse Z-transform to find the input-output relationship in time domaim. 
[image: Figure 01: 50 Hz pure signal]

[image]

In the first image, I have used a pure 50 Hz signal as input. The peak-peak amplitude has reduced a little in the output of the first-order filter. It has reduced a lot in the output of the second-order filter.[Cutoff 60 Hz]

In the second image, I have used a mixed signal of 50 Hz and 1000 Hz signal as input. Output peak to peak amplitude is reduced as before but the amount is different.[Cutoff 60 Hz]

**My objective is to amplify the output. I cant simply multiply it by 2. Because if an 8-bit DAC is coupled to my microcontroller then anything above 255 will be out of its range. I want to eliminate the offset and amplify the signal as much as possible. Is there any way to find the approximate offset voltage and the maximum possible gain.**

Additional information:
1. The screenshots are from an MS-Excel file. I've already tested it using ATMEGA 16.
2. I will analyze the sound waves less than 120 Hz. Any sound wave above 120 Hz has to be eliminated. I will use two microcontrollers. One for low pass filter and another for FFT. Communication will be 16 bit parallel.
3. Filter Equation:[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If the amplitude will be changing, then your gain multiplier will need to change to make sure that you do not exceed 255.

Comment: @ThePhoton I have edited the description. Please read the bold lines.

Comment: @Aaron how to find that gain multiplier? Is there any mathematical relation?

Comment: If 10Hz is the lowest frequency in your input signal (and you need to be certain about this) then calculate the value of the transfer function at 10Hz. Assuming that the gain is less than 1, use 1/gain as your multiplier.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem: what you really want is a *proper* filter that doesn't attenuate the bandpass. What you show in your equation is not an LC lowpass, it's just two RC filters in series, which would make the corner frequency come at -6dB, not -3dB.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I wanted to write RC. But somehow I typed LC. I've edited that.

Comment: And I don't need bandpass.

Comment: I didn't say you need a bandpass, I said you need a filter that does not attenuate the bandpass. I was referring to the passband (feel free to blame my English for that).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I thought that two RC in series will bring the same output as one LC filter. I will check that tomorrow. You might tell it as an answer. Because that was very helpful information.

Comment: First you should decide on what characteristics the filter should have: what type (lowpass, highpass, etc), how much bandwidth at what attenuation (-3dB@10Hz, -1dB@3kHz, etc), how much attenuation@stopband, whether you can afford ripples in passband, or stopband, or both, linear phase or not.

Comment: @SadatRafi an RC filter is **always lossy**.  It has an R, it's physics. An LC can be lossless **if the L and C are ideal**.  In software L and C can be ideal, no parasitics. Therefore two RC in series will not be the same as an LC. You might get the same fall off, but there will always be more attenuation in the passband if there is an R (or two).

Comment: Show your digital filter design.

Comment: @Andyaka I've edited the answer. Look at the bottom.

Comment: Why do you still insist on using that filter, in particular? What made you choose it in the first place? What (more) requirements do you have that the selected filter (I'm a bit reluctant to call it that) can achieve? When I say requirements, I mean that simply saying "anything over 120 Hz" is nowhere near enough to begin with.